# How to identify features in an OpenStreetMap layer in QGIS 2.16?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, openlayers-2, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I want identify features in a OSM layer. I saw this tool here [OSM Feature widget](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/osm/openstreetmap.html/)

Where I can find it? Is still in use or is there another option?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this in QGIS without first having the data downloaded... the method suggested below to use the openstreetmap.org website with the 'data layer' option is the best way I've found to identify layers in OSM without downloading them first - then I use the QuickOSM plugin or Overpass API...

Comment: Oh - looks like OSMInfo will do that afterall!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you activate experimental extensions in the extension options you can try the OSMInfo plugin. It may have the functions you are looking for.

Comment: This tool works pretty well while in QGIS. In case you don't also know about it you may also find often it is even easier is to work direct on www.openstreetmap.org using the '?' button at the right of the screen. While this means leaving QGIS it has the advantage of allowing navigation into the history of the data and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The OSM feature widget has been dropped some time ago.

As a replacement, use the QuickOSM plugin. You have to zoom in to see as little objects as possible, then download the data and investigate the layers that will be created by the plugin.

Alternatively, use https://www.openstreetmap.org, zoom in, and enable the map data layer (the last on the list).